# Where do I add user roles for ACL?

Tags: node.js, express

I'm trying to implement ACL into my application and am confused by the documentation.  I have the following lines in my server.js file

```
 var acl           = require('acl');

 acl = new acl(new acl.mongodbBackend(mongoose.connection.db));
 acl.allow('user', ['/units'], ['create']);
```

I have a `user` model that I would like to link to the `user` ACL role.  Where/how do I do this?